# Connect Taco Radiator system to a new Honeywell wireless thermostat

Tags: heating, thermostat

I have a Taco model 572 valve connected to an existing wired Honeywell TH8110 thermostat for my oil fueled radiator system.  I'm getting a new Honeywell TH6320 wireless thermostat for a new A/C installation and I would like to know if there is equipment available that would allow me to connect the wireless thermostat to the Taco valve.  The Taco valve is currently connected to a Honeywell control board.

Comment: Have you tired contacting Honeywell? Their customer support is top notch.

Comment: I've contacted taco, I will try Honeywell and see what they tell me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be much easier than I expected.  The EIM that had been setup for A/C only had the `R Rc Rh` terminals connected by jumpers.

- I removed the jumper on the `Rh` terminal because the heating system
  had it's own 24V power.
- I replaced the wire that was coming from the old wired thermostat with a new one that I connected to the `Rh` terminal and `W` terminal on the EIM.

The thermostat had already been connected to the EIM so these steps were all it took.